# What 'type' of a word is the word "goings-on"?

Tags: grammatical-number, word-usage, suffixes

I'm not sure how to phrase this correctly, but I noticed that the word "goings-on" has the plural suffix of '-s' before the end of the word. If this wasn't the case, it would be "going-ons" which of course sounds disgusting and just flat-out doesn't work, but I was wondering how you would describe a word like this; what do you call a word that uses a plural suffix before the very end of the word? And are there any other examples of this kind of word?

Comment: Hint: It's one that’s more like like *breakings in* or *passers by* or *washings up* or *puttings out* than it is like *men at arms* or *ladies in waiting* let alone *attorneys general* or *knights errant*, however you care to punctuate any of those.

Comment: I know this is incredibly late, but I think words with a similar rule would be "brothers-in-law" or "mothers-in-law."